# python3で8個のshape（６，１）データを（8，6）の形にしたい

Tags: python3, numpy, array

8個のShape（6，1）データを（8，6）データに変換する方法をどなたか教えていただけないでしょうか？
例えば
print(A.shape)が
(6，1)
(6，1)
(6，1)
(6，1)
(6，1)
(6，1)
(6，1)
(6，1)
となるのを
print(B.shape)
(8,6)
のようにしたいです。

```
for k in range(8)
    tmp=A[6][1][k]
    for i in range(6)   
        B[k][i]=tmp
```

のような感じでしょうか。

Comment: それは「変換規則」ではなくて「変換例」っす。やはり変換規則が想像つかないっす。

Comment: コードを貼る場合は前後の表に ``` (バッククォート三つ) を挿入するとハイライトされ見やすくなります。

Comment: numpyの配列なのだからnumpyの機能で変換すれば良いのでは？ [NumPy配列ndarrayの形状を変換するreshapeの使い方と-1の意味](https://note.nkmk.me/python-numpy-reshape-usage/) それから元々の質問記事の方も、`pc.pcoef()`の戻り値がnumpy配列で返ってくるのを代入する際の指定方法が良くないのかもしれませんね。[NumPy配列ndarrayの要素・行・列を取得（抽出）、代入](https://note.nkmk.me/python-numpy-select-element-row-column-array/) それを正しく処理すれば、この質問自体が不要になりそうです。

Comment: 一応自己解決いたしましたのでこの質問は削除しましょうか？

Comment: SO では自己回答も推奨されていますので、質問削除よりは自己回答していただくと皆が（あなたおよび読者）ハッピーになれると思います。

Answer (score 1):

下記のようにして自己解決しました。

```
for k in range(8):
　　　　co=coef.reshape([6])
      　for i in range(6):
                cm_coef[k][i]=co[i]
```